# Weird performance drop

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Welcome everyone! 
I am facing a weird drop of performance for my symfony2 app using MongoDB.
The query that creates the problem is the following:

```
$posts=$dm->getRepository('ngNearBundle:Posts')
                  ->findBy(array('author'=>new \MongoId($userId)), array('date' => -1),5);
```

for a user (the first ever in the database) , the whole page loads in 100ms. For another user, it takes 500ms.

**MY ASSUMPTION**

---

The first user has almost 140K posts, where the second has barely 3 posts, so in order to gather the limit (5 posts) the cursor should navigate all the database looking for 5 posts but finds only 3.

If you agree with my assumption, how can I fix this problem, can Indexes help me out here ?

I have an index on the field author though.. is it because 99% of posts was written by user 1 so it's easy for Mongo to fetch data for that user?
Please enlighten me.

Comment: If you have an index on `{ author : 1 }` then MongoDB should find the user's posts efficiently and know to stop early when finding just 3 for the second user, but it will have to sort the results to get the most recent 5, which is significant for the 140K post user. Try an index on `{author : 1, date : -1 }`. I'm not sure why the query for the second user would be slow. The page loads slower but it's not confirmed it's the database's slowness. Try running a [.explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) on the queries and posting the output here.

Comment: That was it Bro! the date should have been indexed reversely 
You can post it as answer, I'll upvote & accept